# rake assets:precompile not working on heroku - foundation and heroku failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation

I already tried different versions of rails-sass but this did not help.

Rails with Foundation fail to upload on Heroku:
Precompiling assets failed.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?
Bootstap is also giving me the same error....

```
marc@marc-ThinkPad-W510:~/Projects/provisionen2$ git push heroku master
    Counting objects: 81, done.
    Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
    Compressing objects: 100% (57/57), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (60/60), 55.95 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
    Total 60 (delta 36), reused 0 (delta 0)
    remote: Compressing source files... done.
    remote: Building source:
    remote: 
    remote: -----> Ruby app detected
    remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
    remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
    remote: -----> Installing dependencies using 1.9.7
    remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
    remote:        Rubygems 2.0.14 is not threadsafe, so your gems must be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
    remote:        Using rake 10.4.2
    remote:        Using i18n 0.7.0
    remote:        Using json 1.8.3
    remote:        Using minitest 5.7.0
    remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.5
    remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.2
    remote:        Using activesupport 4.2.0
    remote:        Using builder 3.2.2
    remote:        Using erubis 2.7.0
    remote:        Using mini_portile 0.6.2
    remote:        Using nokogiri 1.6.6.2
    remote:        Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
    remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.6
    remote:        Using loofah 2.0.2
    remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
    remote:        Using actionview 4.2.0
    remote:        Using rack 1.6.4
    remote:        Using rack-test 0.6.3
    remote:        Using actionpack 4.2.0
    remote:        Using globalid 0.3.5
    remote:        Using activejob 4.2.0
    remote:        Using mime-types 2.6.1
    remote:        Using mail 2.6.3
    remote:        Using actionmailer 4.2.0
    remote:        Using activemodel 4.2.0
    remote:        Using arel 6.0.0
    remote:        Using activerecord 4.2.0
    remote:        Using coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1
    remote:        Using execjs 2.5.2
    remote:        Using coffee-script 2.4.1
    remote:        Using thor 0.19.1
    remote:        Using railties 4.2.0
    remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.1.0
    remote:        Using multi_json 1.11.1
    remote:        Using jbuilder 2.3.0
    remote:        Using jquery-rails 4.0.4
    remote:        Using pg 0.18.2
    remote:        Using bundler 1.9.7
    remote:        Using sprockets 3.2.0
    remote:        Using sprockets-rails 2.3.1
    remote:        Using rails 4.2.0
    remote:        Using rdoc 4.2.0
    remote:        Using sass 3.4.15
    remote:        Using tilt 1.4.1
    remote:        Using sass-rails 5.0.3
    remote:        Using sdoc 0.4.1
    remote:        Using turbolinks 2.5.3
    remote:        Using uglifier 2.7.1
    remote:        Bundle complete! 13 Gemfile dependencies, 48 gems now installed.
    remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
    remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
    remote:        Bundle completed (0.59s)
    remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
    remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
    remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
    remote:        rake aborted!
    remote:        Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'foundation' with type 'application/javascript'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:15
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/resolve.rb:64:in `resolve!'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:399:in `resolve'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:207:in `process_require_directive'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:180:in `block in process_directives'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:178:in `each'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:178:in `process_directives'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:83:in `_call'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:68:in `call'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:86:in `load_asset_by_uri'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:45:in `block in load'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:155:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:38:in `load'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/utils.rb:183:in `dfs'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:86:in `load_asset_by_uri'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:45:in `block in load'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:155:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:38:in `load'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:63:in `find_asset'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:70:in `find_all_linked_assets'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:138:in `block in find'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:223:in `block in stat_tree'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:207:in `block in stat_directory'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:204:in `each'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:204:in `stat_directory'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:222:in `stat_tree'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:136:in `find'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:162:in `compile'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-3.2.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
    remote:        /tmp/build_f0b892a940e4d998bffcb7988f833c42/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'
    remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
    remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    remote:  !
    remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
    remote:  !
    remote: 
    remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
    remote: 
    remote: Verifying deploy...
    remote: 
    remote: !   Push rejected to ....
    remote: 
    To https://git.heroku.com/...
     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: Fehler beim Versenden einiger Referenzen nach 'https://git.heroku.com/...'
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

My gemfile looks like this:

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'foundation-rails'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Comment: Error says that a file named foundation.js is missing in your application

Comment: Thank you - did a new  rails g foundation:install

and it worked.